# Need Authorization Header after WSO2 gateway Authorization is Successful

Tags: wso2

I have API configured with OAuth Bearer token in WSO2 gateway. In Postman, i pass the Authorization Bearer token and Gateway authorizes and my service is invoked.

Now i want the authorization token in the Header. Only Body is coming to service. The token in the Header is not coming to the service. What configuration should be done in WSO2 publisher or WSO2 store in order to acheive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In conf/api-manager.xml, change value of "RemoveOAuthHeadersFromOutMessage" to false. Authorization header will not be removed and it will be available in the backend. This change needs to do in the gateway node.